# Weird Question Marks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, minecraft

I'm trying to create a script that pings my Minecraft server to check how many players are online, but for some reason question marks are getting displayed and it makes the whole website look like crap. Here's my PHP file.

```
<script>
    function setOnline(online,max) {
        var on = online;
        var mx = max;

        var main = document.getElementById('status_main');
        main.className = "panel panel-success server-status";

        var title = document.getElementById('status_title');
        title.innerHTML = "Online";

        var body = document.getElementById('status_body');
        body.innerHTML = on + "/" + mx + " Players Online";
    }
</script>

<script>
    function setOffline() {
        var bar = document.getElementById('status');
        bar.className = "panel panel-danger server-status";
        bar.text = "Offline";
    }
</script>
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //IP/host of Minecraft server
$port = 25565; //Minecraft server port, not query port
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); //Create the socket
$connected = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port); //Try and connect using the info provided above
 if (!$connected)
    die(); //No connection could be established

socket_send($socket, "\xFE\x01", 2, 0); //Send the server list ping request (two bytes)
$retVal = socket_recv($socket, &$data, 1024, 0); //Get the info and store it in $data
socket_close($socket); //Close socket

if ($retVal != false && substr($data, 0, 1) == "\xFF") //Ensure we're getting a kick message as expected
{
    $data = substr($data, 9); //Remove packet, length and starting characters
    $data = explode("\x00\x00", $data); //0000 separated info
    $protocolVersion = $data[0]; //Get it all into separate variables
    $serverVersion = $data[1];
    $motd = $data[2];
    $playersOnline = $data[3];
    $playersMax = $data[4];
    echo ("<script>setOnline('$playersOnline','$playersMax');</script>");
}
else
{
    die();
}
?>
```

Here's what the result looks like when it's called:
http://cl.ly/image/3o2f3P121q0m

How can I get rid of the question marks?

Comment: I guess you are not cleaning up the string properly. There still seems to be metadata contained in it, or you are not extracting the right data. You can get rid of the questions marks my extracting the right data.

Comment: can you give the char codes for each character in $playersOnline and $playersMax and the value you're expecting?

Comment: You're saying "0000 separated info", but you only have two "nul" characters in your `explode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a charset issue. The information is not being presented in the way that it was encoded.

You can `var_dump` $data to see its Content-Type.

---

Here is just a hypothesis: the actual encoding is ISO-8859-1, but it is being interpreted as UTF-8 (or UTF-16).

To make the browser use the correct encoding, you can add an HTTP header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

or use a meta tag.

Comment: Using $playersOnline = var_dump(data[3]); just adds 'string(2) "9"' to the bottom left corner of my website.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting basic concepts, I'm fairly new to this. Thank you for being patient with me =)

Comment: @josephmandex var_dump the entire $data, not just the $data[3]. It should look similar to `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2009 08:56:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 2005 13:24:10 GMT
ETag: "b80f4-1b6-80bfd280"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 438
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: I added it here: $data = explode("\x00\x00", $data); 
    var_dump($data);
    $protocolVersion = $data[0]; 
but it just prints some random data to the bottom of my website [link](http://mctekkit.net/)

Comment: @josephmandex I don't see anything at the bottom of your website.

Comment: @josephmandex And the number appears to be displaying correctly now.